# c# Getting runtime error. Why?

Tags: c#, .net

Hey im trying to solve this problem but Kattis says i get runtime error which means uncaught exception. 
https://open.kattis.com/problems/fizzbuzz

Is there anything that ive missed in my code that crashes the app?

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string line = "";
    while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != "0")
    {

        var numbers = line.Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToList();
        int x = numbers[0];
        int y = numbers[1];
        int N = numbers[2];
        for(int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
        {
            bool found = false;
            bool found2 = false;
            if(i % x == 0)
            {
                if(i % y==0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("FizzBuzz");
                    found2 = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Fizz");
                    found = true;                           
                }
            }
            if(i % y == 0 && !found2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Buzz");
                found = true;
            }
            if(!found && !found2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
        }
       }
}
```

Comment: What exceptions do you get when you run the code?

Comment: Which error is the line occurring on?

Comment: I feel like you are just trying to advertise a site to me...

Comment: When you debug, what is the exception?  Which line throws the exception?  Don't ignore errors, the system is *telling you* the problem.

Comment: Kattis doesnt say which line it is.. @musefan im just trying to solve the problems on the site.. Im sorry if i upset you

Comment: Why don't you just do a `else if` and `else` then you won't need the `found` and `found2` variables.

Comment: @R.B Does Kattis at least tell you the input it feds to your code?  If so, you can just run your code on that input.  If not it's going to be hard to determine the issue, but try running the code yourself with different inputs.

Comment: Yup ive tried the 4 samples that they give me and they all work. So i cant figure out what is wrong

Comment: You have to *validate* the input: all the items in `line` are integers; they are not `0`, there're at least 3 of them...

Comment: @R.B: Start by running this code *on your computer* in a debugger.  (There's a free version of Visual Studio.)  You might also try a Google search for "C# exception handling" and look into how to handle exceptions.  We can all *guess* what *might* be wrong, and there could be *multiple* things wrong.  But until you can actually tell us what the error is, everything is a guess.

Comment: I'm not sure the `while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != "0")` makes sense since it says the input will be a single test case.  Try just removing the `while` loop.

Comment: @juharr Ah that was it. It got accepted! Rookie mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The way I read that problem is that you'll be given one line of 3 numbers on the console.  So you should only be doing one `ReadLine`.  I suggest removing the `while` loop and just do.

```
var numbers = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing guaranties you that `numbers` has at least Length 3 or even 1.
This means that all the following lines can raise index out of bounds exception:

```
int y = numbers[1];
int N = numbers[2];
```

So you need to check `numbers.Length` before assigning above lines

Comment: But how do you know that's the specific error in this case?